# jQuery UI Populate Select Menu from the Database

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

So I have these two jQuery select menus and and based on what is selected in one menu, an ajax call is made to get data for the next select menu. I believe I will have to iterate over data and list items to populate the html for the second select when the 'selectmenu' event of the first select is triggered. I've been looking at the structure of the select menu and I see the div's at the bottom of the page for both selects are like.

```
<div class="ui-selectmenu-menu ui-front"></div>
```

Ofcourse one that has options shows populated li tags whereas the other one only shows one empty li item.

My questions is that once I iterate and create the html markup for second select. How do I know which div to append that in? Both have the same classes on the outermost container (Div): ui-selectmenu-menu ui-front

Thank you!

Comment: perhaps you need ID

Comment: In that case use `DOM` traversing to get the next dropdown

Comment: @MayankPandeyz I guess they are added in the same order as selects. So probably something like $('.ui-selectmenu-menu').eq(1) //for second select. I'm thinking. Order is the key hey I'm hoping they are always in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

So guess I did not have to worry about those Divs. All I needed was to populate the options for the select menu and then call this

```
$('#city).html(cityOptions);
```

Where cityOptions is a string of  tags I generated. By initializing .selectmenu method and then refreshing, the relative Div at the bottom of the page get's updated automatically with all the options and no need to worry about updating it.

```
$('#city').selectmenu().selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use selectpicker for your tasks.
>
> `<select id="city_pickter" class="form-control selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">`
>
> - it allows live searching
> - multiple select
> - easy to use

i suppose you are getting the ids of each city through jquery.

```
// defining array of cities.
var current_cities = [];

// populating cities array
for(var i = 0; i < data.response.cities.length; i++){

    current_cities.push(Number(data.response.cities[i].city_id));
}

$('#city_picker').selectpicker('val', current_cities);
```

**if you want to deselect everything. you can use**

```
$('#city_picker').selectpicker('val', '[]');
```

> JavaScript and CSS file required for the above code to work are

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info on selectpicker but I don't have a choice. Application already has datepicker so I have to stick with it.